# remote: Forbidden fatal: unable to access

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket

I have access to repo, I clone it by https, then I made my changes and I commit those change and create `new_branch` and try to push I got this:

```
git push origin new_branch
remote: Forbidden
fatal: unable to access 'https://username@bitbucket.org/main-account/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I already setup my SSH key, git global config and already logged

```
ssh -T username@bitbucket.org
logged in as username

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

also, I tried to change the url

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:main-account/repo.git
```

and when I push I got this

```
git push origin new_branch
Forbidden
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and finally my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
        UseKeychain yes

Host bitbucket.org
        HostName bitbucket.org
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does git remote show origin say?

Comment: Given you're getting 'Forbidden' access errors from both HTTPS and SSH, are you sure you have access to the repo? Maybe you only have read-only access: can you `git fetch`? (I'd guess that's not it - the SSH error says 'read'.) Do you definitely have the correct path?

Comment: @Christoph check here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/KxgbE5jP

Comment: Do you have 2FA (2 factor authn) enabled? I use github and I had to create access key when 2FA is enabled, regular user name password or ssh keys won't work with 2FA.

Comment: no i didn't enabled it @MohanaRao

Comment: Are there IP restrictions on that repo? The team that owns the repo would set those.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `username` and `main-account` are the same: you need to push back to a repository that you own (have created as username)

Or you need to have [been granted repository access](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/grant-repository-access-to-users-and-groups-221449716.html) to `username` by their owner `main-account`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an access on Bitbucket.

To check, you can: log into Bitbucket > Profile & settings > Personal setting > App Passwords > Select / grant required access.

Answer (score 0):

To check, you can: log into Bitbucket > Profile & settings > Personal setting > App Passwords > Select / grant required access. > ne token will be generated for you. Make a note of that and use it when you upload / push code to bitbucket.